# QPushButton icon not appearing

Tags: python, pyqt

I created a button like this:

```
icontest = QtGui.QIcon('test.gif');
self.TestButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Test")
self.TestButton.setEnabled(False)
self.TestButton.setIcon(icontest)
self.TestButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(25, 25))
self.TestButton.clicked.connect(goToTestHandler)
self.layout.addWidget(self.TestButton, 0, 1)
... some loading ...
self.TestButton.setEnabled(True)
```

the button appears, but without the icon - no exception thrown

Comment: Did you do any basic debugging? For instance, what happens if you use an absolute path to your gif file? Also, what output do you get from `print os.path.isfile('test.gif'), os.path.abspath('test.gif')`.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce that behavior only when the path passed to the `QIcon` constructor is wrong. Otherwise the icon is displayed.

Comment: so what is wrong in my path? the icon is in same directory as code and other files read by the open() function - I address it the same way

Comment: Then I don't know what can be the problem. As I said the only way I'm able to reproduce your problem is using a wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a button with image in a table cell and the image is appering and working . here is the code.

```
    newitem = QPushButton(self)
    newitem.setFlat(True)
    newitem.setAutoFillBackground(True)

    palette = newitem.palette();
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Button,QColor(255,255,255));
    newitem.setPalette(palette);
    newitem.setIcon(QIcon("__32__Setting-icon.png"));
    newitem.setIconSize(QSize(22,22));
    self.job_table.setCellWidget(self.table_job_rowCount,6,newitem )
```

Answer (score 0):

For my experience, you can use absolute path instead of relative path in Qt.
Like `C:/xxx/xxx.jpg`

Edit:
Or maybe you can see [this](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qresource-system/) to know more about the `Qt resource system` to show your icons perfectly.